# Finding location of dropdown option via Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I've searched around these past 2 days and have not found a solution that works. I'm currently on Python 3.6.4 on OSX and v3.11.0 Selenium with chromedriver.

So what i'm hoping to achieve is to find the coordinates of a dropdown option tag with innerHTML matching a given string.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select id="product-select" name="id" class="">
    <option value="1532273459205">Small</option>
    <option value="1532273491973">Medium</option>
    <option value="1532273524741">Large</option>
    <option value="1532273557509">X-Large</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

My Code (I also added a .click() for the dropdown before this code to ensure that the dropdown is actually visible):

```
size = input("What size do you want?")
for option in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
                 if (option.get_attribute('innerHTML')) == size:
                     print(option.location)
```

However, this returns a dictionary of `{'x':0, 'y':0}`.

Since it did not return an error, i'm guessing that it's because the element isn't visible. Hence, i researched more and tried adding this to my code above. 
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//option')))

However, this still doesn't work can still gives 0,0 as the coordinates. I'm still quite a newbie so maybe there's something i'm not catching here. Thanks so much in advance and if you guys need more info please tell me! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the option’s coordinates?

Comment: @ian I'm hoping to create some sort of script to click on specific coordinates corresponding to the size input!

Comment: How exactly did you plan on using the coordinates? I.e., what Selenium calls were you going to make with them? Are you just trying to select an option in a dropdown? Or is there some specific reason you want to try to execute a raw mouse click?

Comment: Oh i was planning on feeding the coordinates to pyautogui for the mouse clicks on another chrome session( a normal one), so i don't think the select method will work

Comment: Why do you need another Chrome session? Why not control that session with Selenium too?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is select an option, there's no need to gather the element coordinates. Selenium provides [`Select()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) for just this purpose:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

sizes = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("product-select"))
sizes.select_by_visible_text("Large")
```